# How to delete or remove a given number of entries from a Redis stream?

Tags: redis

Redis [`XTRIM`](https://redis.io/commands/xtrim) command allows you to state how many entries to keep, but what if I want to state how many entries to delete instead?

For example, if I have a stream that is constantly receiving new entries, I want to delete the oldest 100 entries, I cannot simply do `XLEN myStream` and then call `XTRIM myStream MAXLEN <xlen result - 100>`, as new entries are added between the two commands, and it will delete more than 100 entries.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [Lua Script](https://redis.io/commands/eval), to atomically evaluate the current number of `myStreams` entries and then call `XTRIM` accordingly.

```
EVAL "local streamLen = redis.call('XLEN', KEYS[1]) \n if streamLen >= tonumber(ARGV[1]) then \n return redis.call('XTRIM', KEYS[1], 'MAXLEN', streamLen - tonumber(ARGV[1])) \n else return redis.error_reply(KEYS[1]..' has less than '..ARGV[1]..' items') end" 1 myStream 100
```

Let's take a look at the Lua script:

```
local streamLen = redis.call('XLEN', KEYS[1])
if streamLen >= tonumber(ARGV[1]) then 
    return redis.call('XTRIM', KEYS[1], 'MAXLEN', streamLen - tonumber(ARGV[1]))
else
    return redis.error_reply(KEYS[1]..' has less than '..ARGV[1]..' items')
end
```

This gets the length of the stream into `streamLen`, and then deletes the desired number of entries by calculating the difference and passing it to `XTRIM`. As Lua scripts run atomically, there will be no new entries added between the `XLEN` and the `XTRIM` commands.

The Lua script, and therefore the `EVAL` command, returns the number of deleted entries, and it should match the number passed as argument unless there are fewer entries in the stream, in which case it returns `(error) myStream has less than 100 items`.

If you want to **remove up to n entries**, removing less if there are fewer entries in the stream, make a simple change to the Lua script:

```
local streamLen = redis.call('XLEN', KEYS[1])
if streamLen >= tonumber(ARGV[1]) then 
    return redis.call('XTRIM', KEYS[1], 'MAXLEN', streamLen - tonumber(ARGV[1]))
else
    return redis.call('XTRIM', KEYS[1], 'MAXLEN', tonumber(ARGV[1]))
end
```

The time complexity of both Lua scripts is O(N), with N being the number of evicted entries, because `XLEN` is O(1) and `XTRIM` is O(N).

Comment: Hopefully, this will be resolved in a future version of Redis: https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/6640